# Google map failed load

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, api-key

I am creating a simple map application .I  successfully implemented google map im my activity but failed to move camera , add marker or any other operation .

This is logcat I have:

```
07-26 08:16:05.820: I/dalvikvm(16116): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lgln;'
07-26 08:16:05.820: W/dalvikvm(16116): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
07-26 08:16:05.820: E/dalvikvm(16116): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method glt.a
07-26 08:16:05.820: W/dalvikvm(16116): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lglt;
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I show you how I solved the same problem you have.

First of all, I cleaned all sdk and I downloaded again Google Play Services lib. Then I removed .android folder of my computer and I regenerated my debug.keystore.

After that, I just get my new SHA1 to obtain my Google Maps V2 Api Key.

After update my apikey, let's see how I change my code.

Now I use fragment with MapFragment insted of MapView in your xml layout.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

And use FragmentManager to locate it:

```
   public class MapsActivity extends Activity
{
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    //map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    try 
    {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(MapsActivity.this);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: all my code is  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);}  and <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />